# ocean simulation in Blender vs. Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I want to make an ocean simulation that is physically accurate. 
The height and speed of the waves should be controlled by the keyboard at runtime.
In the ocean, there needs to be a boat that either moves along a path or is controlled by the keyboard. 
So far I have made this simulation in Blender:
https://youtu.be/LJ6ncxv-k7w
The problems are as follows:
1. There is no collision with the ocean
2. There are no controllers for the boat's movement
3. I am able to control the waves, but not at runtime

I thought about switching to Unity because the user interface is obviously better, as it is a game engine. I do not want to use Blender's game engine as its future is uncertain at this point. 
After reviewing the various Unity water simulation plugins, I came to these conclusions:
1. the buoyancy is great in most of them, such as in [Aquas](https://youtu.be/A3JTLXGqxgw) and [SUIMONO](https://youtu.be/7IUb299OeZg)
2. None of them seems to offer a physically realistic collision with the boat.
3. they do offer wave height control, but not much else as far as wave properties go.
4. Some of the plugins can be combined to get closer to satisfactory results.
My question is:
Should I go with Unity completely? 
It seems perfect for my user control needs, but the plugins are lacking in the collision aspect. I came across this video, but no tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0D_vrYm4FQ 
Even if there was one, how could I combine it with the plugins?
Is there a way to build the scene in Blender and then import it into Unity?
Would I be able to control the waves and boat after importing them?

Thank you very much for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Blender's game engine's future is not uncertain...it is gone in 2.8. It may be replaced by something completely new in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if you really means an ocean, i suggest you to check out [NVIDIA WaveWorks](https://developer.nvidia.com/waveworks). it's a C library and doesn't have an officially integration with Unity3D, but since you go this far for it, i guess maybe you'll have enough courage to trying make it into a useable plugin yourself.